# How can I generate a signed URL for a file in cloud storage that uses the static site URL?

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gcloud-ruby

Say I have a domain, `media.coolsite.com`. Also say I have a bucket in Google Cloud Storage with the same name. I also have the cname setup properly, so that when I visit `media.coolsite.com` in the browser, it renders `index.html` in the bucket.

The bucket also contains a file `01.mp3` that I am trying to get a signed URL for. I can do this with the following code:

```
gcloud = Gcloud.new
storage = gcloud.storage
bucket = storage.bucket 'media.coolsite.com'
file = bucket.file '01.mp3'
signed_url = file.signed_url
```

This returns a URL like so:

https://storage.googleapis.com/media.coolstuff.com/01.mp3?GoogleAccessId=...&Expires=...etc...

But what I would like is a URL like this:

http://media.coolstuff.com/01.mp3?GoogleAccessId=...&Expires=...etc...

Note the different host: `media.coolstuff.com` instead of `storage.googleapis.com`.

How can I do this using the `gcloud` gem?

Comment: Two questions: First, is the switch from https to http intentional in your question?  Second, can you describe the use case for needing the second URL?

Comment: 1) Yes it is intentional because I don't have an SSL cert for that domain, so I assume I cannot use https. 2) It just appears more professional to have your content served from your own domain, and the intent is clearer when link sharing. Amazon lets you do it with a `virtual_host` flag: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html#instance_method_details . The explanation there even talks about https vs http. They default to http, though ideally i'd be able to pick, if I was able to use https with that domain.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Unfortunately, GCS doesn't have support for anything like that right now, so there's no way to do this with a signed URL.  Sorry.

Comment: Yes, GCS does have support for that. The 2nd link in the example above does actually work. Locally, I just use string replacement to replace "s://storage.googleapis.com/" with "//", and that URL works. The gem should support this functionality.