# Use Nginx as Proxy for Google Cloud Storage Signed Url

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-storage, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, pre-signed-url

I am trying to use Nginx as a proxy for Google Cloud Storage signed URLs, both for upload and download.

The result that I am trying to achieve would work in a way that all requests to the Nginx server will be forwarded to Google Cloud Storage with the query parameters intact.

The process to generate the signed URL and make the request travel through the desired loop is as follows.

First, we generate a signed URL using a standard procedure.

```js
// Unnecessary details removed for brevity
// but this code is tested and it works

const options: GetSignedUrlConfig = {
    version: 'v4',
    action: 'write',
    expires: Date.now() + signedUrlExpirationTimeFromConfig * 1000,
    virtualHostedStyle: true,
}

const [signedUrl] = await this.storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .file(remoteFilePath)
    .getSignedUrl(options)
```

Next, when the client uses this signed URL, it replaces the domain to where the Nginx server is running.

When sent, the request hits the Nginx server and it replaces the domain in the signed URL again, restoring it to the original one.

Nginx forwards the request to the original signed URL and sends the response received back to the client.

So, let's say my Nginx server is available at `https://www.noman.me`.

It gets a request `https://noman.me/bucket-name/cat.jpeg?X-Goog-Algorithm= GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=example%40example-project.iam.gserviceaccount .com%2F20181026%2Fus-central1%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20181026T18 1309Z&X-Goog-Expires=900&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=247a2aa45f16 9edf4d187d54e7cc46e4731b1e6273242c4f4c39a1d2507a0e58706e25e3a85a7dbb891d62afa849 6def8e260c1db863d9ace85ff0a184b894b117fe46d1225c82f2aa19efd52cf21d3e2022b3b868dc c1aca2741951ed5bf3bb25a34f5e9316a2841e8ff4c530b22ceaa1c5ce09c7cbb5732631510c2058 0e61723f5594de3aea497f195456a2ff2bdd0d13bad47289d8611b6f9cfeef0c46c91a455b94e90a 66924f722292d21e24d31dcfb38ce0c0f353ffa5a9756fc2a9f2b40bc2113206a81e324fc4fd6823 a29163fa845c8ae7eca1fcf6e5bb48b3200983c56c5ca81fffb151cca7402beddfc4a76b13344703 2ea7abedc098d2eb14a7`.

The request is forwarded to `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/cat.jpeg?X-Goog-Algorithm= GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=example%40example-project.iam.gserviceaccount .com%2F20181026%2Fus-central1%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20181026T18 1309Z&X-Goog-Expires=900&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=247a2aa45f16 9edf4d187d54e7cc46e4731b1e6273242c4f4c39a1d2507a0e58706e25e3a85a7dbb891d62afa849 6def8e260c1db863d9ace85ff0a184b894b117fe46d1225c82f2aa19efd52cf21d3e2022b3b868dc c1aca2741951ed5bf3bb25a34f5e9316a2841e8ff4c530b22ceaa1c5ce09c7cbb5732631510c2058 0e61723f5594de3aea497f195456a2ff2bdd0d13bad47289d8611b6f9cfeef0c46c91a455b94e90a 66924f722292d21e24d31dcfb38ce0c0f353ffa5a9756fc2a9f2b40bc2113206a81e324fc4fd6823 a29163fa845c8ae7eca1fcf6e5bb48b3200983c56c5ca81fffb151cca7402beddfc4a76b13344703 2ea7abedc098d2eb14a7` which means the entire URL remains intact but only the domain is changed.

I would also want it to function in a way that the responses from Google are forwarded to the client by Nginx.

So far, this is the configuration I arrived at but it does not seem to work.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name noman.me;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/front-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/front-error.log;

  client_max_body_size 100M;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/$uri?$query_string;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    # proxy_pass http://172.21.0.2:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS';
      #
      # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
      #
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
      #
      # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
      #
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }

    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
    }

    if ($request_method = 'PUT') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, OPTIONS' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
    }

    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
    }
  }
}
```

Before there is a suggestion to use a load balancer with the bucket as the backend, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76655987/google-cloud-storage-upload-fails-for-large-files-when-signed-url-has-domain)

Answer (score 0):

The `hostname` is part of the generated signature. You cannot forward a signed URL to a different host. Google expects the hostname to be `https://storage.googleapis.com`. If you sign using a different hostname, the signature verification will fail.

Also, the bucket name is part of the hostname:

```
{bucket_name}.storage.googleapis.com
```

You can read more about the Cloud Storage Version 4 signature:

[V4 signing process with your own program](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually)

Comment: With a little URL re-writing in Nginx, all of this can be taken care of. In the end, Nginx uses the generated URL to proxy the request so it should work fine. The only difference is the client sends the request to Nginx. Google Cloud Storage only cares that the exact signed URL is called, not from where it is being called.

Comment: @NomanUrRehman - Yes, I agree that the source host does not matter but the signed URL is wrong, so that must be corrected first.

Comment: I understand but why would the signed url not work when only the domain is changed? The server returns the original url with Google domain. The client changes the domain in the signed url and sends the request. The Nginx server upon receiving the request, changes the domain back to Google and forwards the request.

Comment: @NomanUrRehman - Your question does not include details on how you generated the Signed URL or any transformations you applied. Details matter to get a correct/good answer.

Comment: Sorry! I have added more details to the question.

Comment: @NomanUrRehman - I see your new update. Why are you creating a Signed URL, transforming it, and sending the URL to Nginx? Once the client has a signed URL, the client should directly use the URL to fetch/post content with Cloud Storage. Your implementation adds complexity and reduces reliability. I cannot see any benefit to your strategy. If I am missing something let me know. You say that your method does not work. What does not work? What is the exact error message? When a signed URL fails, Google returns an XML data structure with precise details. Add that error to your post.

Comment: One of our clients cannot use the signed URL because their infrastructure policy sees the URL as fishy so they get a 403. However, when they hit our domain for upload, everything works. This is the reason I am going with such a solution. The original idea was to put the bucket behind a load balancer but Google support told us that the load balancer does not support upload.
I can add the errors but fundamentally, I am long way off so I am not sure they will help but I can add them later.
However, I feel this is a breeze for any Nginx expert which unfortunately, my question has not run into.

Comment: @NomanUrRehman - Your problem is not with Nginx at this point. If you review the error message from Google you will know why the signed URL was rejected. However, since it appears that you must proxy Cloud Storage, I would not use Signed URLs at all. Your design approach in wrong IMHO.